# Determine whether or not( (x+y+z)==(p+q+r) and E1==E2 and (x!=p or y!=q or z!=r))

Tags: number-theory, logic, systems-of-equations

there are two number E1 and E2

$$E1=Ax + By + Cz  \quad\mbox{and}\quad E2=Ap + Bq + Cr$$

Value of $A,B,C$ are different and positive integers.

Value of $x,y,z,p,q,r$ may be same and they are positive integers.

can we have any value for $A,B,C,x,y,z,p,q,r$ such that following condition will be true ?

$((x+y+z)==(p+q+r ) and E1==E2$ and $(x\neq p$ or $y \neq q$ or $z\neq r) )$

Comment: Do you mean for any value of $A,B,C$? Or can the values of these constants be chosen? If this is the case I could choose $A=B$, $x=q$ and $y=p$ (in general $x\neq p$ and $y\neq q$), finding the same value

Comment: @seoanes No ,,value of A and B and C can not be equals ,, i mentioned it in my question already,, value of x,y,z,p,q,r, can be equal

Answer (score 0):

what you get is next two equations
$$Ax+By+Cz=Ap+Bq+Cr\\
x+y+z=p+q+r$$
Imagine $A,B,C$ are fixed. You get two equations for 6 variables. You can choose 4 them as you want, and the other two will be determined by the two equations.

So, answering your question: Yes, it is always possible

Comment: sorry that was my fault,, i forget to add one more condition there should be x+y+z==p+q+r

Comment: try to edit your post, instead of commenting. It could be useful if future readers find similar questions